# Is there a roadmap/guide-lines to archieve the badges

Tags: support, badges, guidelines

I want to archieve the silver/gold badges but not sure how to. It would be lovely to have a roadmap/guid-lines for new users like me to follow. Are there ones?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want to archive the silver/gold badges"* ?

Comment: I have update my question. Sorry for incorrect dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a few things:

- give good answers to questions
- ask good or interesting questions
- vote
- visit the site at least once each day
- edit wisely (if you have the reputation)

There are a lot of badges, some are easy some are very hard, some require a bit of luck. If you really want to go for gold, the easiest way is to be active for 100 days in a row.  But you can also become an expert in a certain field to get the 1000+ upvotes needed to get the expert badge.

But beware, badges are just the sugar on the pie. Its fun to collect as much as possible, but Q&A is still the main part of the site.

By the way, as you have several accepted answers with 0 score, you may expect the unsung hero badge soon.

Answer (score 1):

Fair warning:  I'm assuming you mean "achieve" not "archive".

There isn't a roadmap or guide to getting the badges.  The idea is just to use the site and be surprised when you get a badge.

Aside from that, just read through the [badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) page and you'll see how to get each badge that is available.

There is also [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/140548) that you can use to see what the badges are.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question. Thank you for your helpful links.